# Best tool to use to extract command output

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, nmap

I want to programatically process the results of nmap output but cannot work out how to take the output and extract just the details of the protocol or port tables shown in the two outputs below.

I am pretty confident I can use awk for processing the table data - but I cannot extract just that from the output... What combination of tools could be used to do this?

```
$ sudo nmap --open -sO 10.100.0.14
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-27 19:15 AEDT
Warning: 10.100.0.14 giving up on port because retransmission cap hit (10).
Nmap scan report for teichos.mydomain.net (10.100.0.14)
Host is up (0.00030s latency).
Not shown: 250 filtered protocols, 1 closed protocol
PROTOCOL STATE         SERVICE
1        open          icmp
33       open|filtered dccp
80       open|filtered iso-ip
117      open|filtered iatp
136      open|filtered udplite
MAC Address: 6A:3A:ED:33:9E:00 (Unknown)
```

Output 2:

```
$ sudo nmap -sS 10.100.0.14 -p-
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-27 19:30 AEDT
Nmap scan report for teichos.mydomain.net (10.100.0.14)
Host is up (0.00024s latency).
Not shown: 65533 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
9090/tcp open  zeus-admin
MAC Address: 6A:3A:ED:33:9E:00 (Unknown)
```

The output I am looking for is as follows (the headings are not essential):

```
PROTOCOL STATE         SERVICE
1        open          icmp
33       open|filtered dccp
80       open|filtered iso-ip
117      open|filtered iatp
136      open|filtered udplite
```

and

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
9090/tcp open  zeus-admin
```

Comment: Check `man nmap` for `OUTPUT`: lots of options there. No need to break your head running `awk` on a mixed output when you can prepare the output properly first. `nmap -options | egrep '^[0-9]'` should also work.

Comment: How exactly should your output look like?

Comment: @RudiC:  I don't have any output. I want to parse the output and check that only the ports that should be open are open. The -oX should do the trick. I missed it in the doco. (Thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov) - and egrep is even easier.

Comment: @Bryon yes, but in order to help you get the output you want, we need to know what the output you want is. We can easily help you parse this, but you need to tell us what you need first. As it stands, we have no idea what your final result is supposed to be so we can't help.

Comment: @terdon - sure thing. I have clarified the question above. But the xml format by using the -oX option actually does the trick much better. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nmap` utility allows for outputting easily parsable XML if given the `-oX` option, which means you can recreate the table if you wish, or extract whatever information from it that you need.

The pipeline below uses `xmlstarlet` to extract information from the generated XML document, and recreates the table found in the ordinary `nmap` output, with an extra column inserted with the "reason" for the given "state".

The output from `nmap` is parsed by `xmlstarlet`, which inserts `#` characters (an arbitrary character that we don't expect to be part of the output) for column delimiters, and `column` is use to create the final aligned table.

```bsh
sudo nmap -oX - --open -sO localhost |
xmlstarlet sel -t -m /nmaprun/host/ports/port \
    -v @portid -o '#' \
    -v state/@state -o '#' \
    -v state/@reason -o '#' \
    -v service/@name -nl |
column -s '#' -t
```

Example output:

```
1    open           echo-reply      icmp
4    open|filtered  no-response     ipv4
6    open           proto-response  tcp
17   open           port-unreach    udp
41   open|filtered  no-response     ipv6
50   open|filtered  no-response     esp
51   open|filtered  no-response     ah
97   open|filtered  no-response     etherip
112  open|filtered  no-response     vrrp
137  open|filtered  no-response     mpls-in-ip
240  open|filtered  no-response
255  open|filtered  no-response
```

Again, but only extracting the "filtered" responses:

```bsh
sudo nmap -oX - --open -sO localhost |
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/nmaprun/host/ports/port[contains(state/@state,"filtered")]'  \
    -v @portid -o '#' \
    -v state/@state -o '#' \
    -v state/@reason -o '#' \
    -v service/@name -nl |
column -s '#' -t
```

Example output:

```
4    open|filtered  no-response  ipv4
41   open|filtered  no-response  ipv6
50   open|filtered  no-response  esp
51   open|filtered  no-response  ah
97   open|filtered  no-response  etherip
112  open|filtered  no-response  vrrp
137  open|filtered  no-response  mpls-in-ip
240  open|filtered  no-response
255  open|filtered  no-response
```

Answer (score 2):

With the specific output you show, we can simply select all lines that start either with a digit or with a capital `P` (for the headers):

```
sudo nmap ... | grep -E '^([0-9]|P)'
```

I created two text files, `nmap1` and `nmap2` with the two outputs from your question to test, and get:

```
$ grep -E '^([0-9]|P)' nmap1 
PROTOCOL STATE         SERVICE
1        open          icmp
33       open|filtered dccp
80       open|filtered iso-ip
117      open|filtered iatp
136      open|filtered udplite

$ grep -E '^([0-9]|P)' nmap2
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
9090/tcp open  zeus-admin
```

You can also do it in `awk` if you prefer:

```
sudo nmap ... | awk '/^([0-9]|P)/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^(PROTOCOL|PORT)/{f=1} /^MAC/{f=0} f' file
PROTOCOL STATE         SERVICE
1        open          icmp
33       open|filtered dccp
80       open|filtered iso-ip
117      open|filtered iatp
136      open|filtered udplite

$ awk '/^(PROTOCOL|PORT)/{f=1} /^MAC/{f=0} f' file
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
9090/tcp open  zeus-admin
```